# how can a number in the where clause affect a sunquery

Tags: mysql, sql

if the count function in the code gives a number of distinct salaries then what does the '3' in the where clause do?

```
select distinct salary
from worker a
where 3>= (select COUNT(distinct salary)
           from worker b
           where a .salary <=b.salary)
```

Comment: This lists all workers who have less than three workers with higher salary, yes?

Answer (score 2):

This is to get the top three salaries.  However, it is a silly way to do it, because this is much simpler:

```
select distinct salary
from worker w
order by salary desc
limit 3;
```

A correlated subquery is no longer needed for such logic, even in more complicated cases.  MySQL now supports functions such as `rank()` and `row_number()` that do this for you.